# Chechlistbox en WPF

Tags: c#, formularios, windows, wpf

quisiera saber como hacer en WPF un checklistbox como en windows forms, ya que tengo que hacer una migracion de un sistema y no entiendo como.

Ya que tengo un evento programado que es el Item Checked.

desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa si te sirve [esta página](http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/). O también [esta otra](https://merill.net/2009/10/wpf-checked-listbox/)

Answer (score 0):

En `WPF` se puede resolver con un ListBox y redefiniendo el `DataTemplate`, como se plantea aqui

[CheckBoxList in WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/checkboxlist-in-wpf/)

Donde usa

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxZone" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"
 Height="115" Background="Azure">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding TheText}
                 Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked"  
                 Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Asignas la lista de items por medio del `ItemsSource` y haces que el estado del check se asigna a una propiedad de la entidad con `Content="{Binding TheText}`

Para esto necesitas definir una `class` propia que sea parte de una `List<>` observable